# How to split a column of string in a dataframe into multiple rows of subtexts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a  pandas dataframe. This dataframe consists of two columns. One column contains strings of spam email that exceeds the maximum sequence length of transformer models I plan to use on them, and the other contains the labels corresponding to the string. I would like to split the long strings into multiple subtexts in separate rows while retaining their label correspondance.

**Input Dataframe:**

```
Text                                              Label
"This is a very long spam email"                  1
"This is a very long normal email"                0
```

**Desired output:**

```
Maximum Sequence Length = 4

Text                                              Label
"This is a very"                                  1
"long spam email"                                 1
"This is a very"                                  0
"long normal email"                               0
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .split() method to convert the string into a list and then use the .join() method and [ ] to convert the first four elements of the list into a string. Here is my code, if you need it for longer strings, you can add a for loop:

```
def convert(string):
    nlist = string.split(' ')
    nlist1= nlist[:4]
    nlist2= nlist[4:]
    nstring1 = " ".join(nlist1)
    nstring2 = " ".join(nlist2)
    return nstring1, nstring2
    
x = "This is a very long spam email"
print(convert(x))
```

Comment: I know that I could do this in an individual string, but I don't know how to do this in a dataframe while preserving the subtext's correspondence with the labels. I was told that it is dangerous to do it through iterrows().

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm overwhelmed by that, I haven't really dealt with dataframes yet

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Text" : ["This is a very very very very long spam spam span email email", "This is a a a a very long long long normal email"],
              "Label" : [1,0]})
>>> print(df.to_string())
                                                            Text  Label
0  This is a very very very very long spam spam span email email      1
1               This is a a a a very long long long normal email      0
```

Solution:

```
>>> df = (df.apply(lambda x:x.Text.split(), axis=1)
       .apply(lambda x: [x[i * 4:(i + 1) * 4] for i in range((len(x) + 4 - 1) // 4 )])
       .explode()
       .to_frame(name="Text")
>>> df.Text = df.Text.apply(' '.join)
>>> df.reset_index().rename(columns={"index" : "Label"})[["Text", "Label"]]

    Text                    Label
0   This is a very          1
1   very very very long     1
2   spam spam span email    1
3   email                   1
4   This is a a             0
5   a a very long           0
6   long long normal email  0
```

Comment: I barely understand how this works but this is perfect! You're a lifesaver!